# How can I replace `{ lock_guard lock(obj.mut); obj.a_stringstream << a << b /*...*/ << n;}` with a method call

Tags: c++, oop, methods

I have a `struct` like

```
struct log {
    boost::mutex mut;
    std::stringstream a_stringstream;
    //...
    };
```

and in my code I have a vector of those and frequently do

```
{
    boost::lock_guard <boost::mutex> lock(logs[AN_ENUM].mut);
    logs[AN_ENUM].a_stringstream << "something" << a_double << a_string << etc;
}
```

It seems verbose to have the lock guard and brackets every time I want to log something. At first I thought maybe I could overload the `<<` operator for my struct, but I read about it and I don't think that can work. Is there a good way that I can condense this into a method call?

Comment: A typical setup is to have the usage `logs[AN_ENUM] << a << b << c;` , where the first `<<` returns an object containing stringstream that takes `<<` whose destructor does all the work.  But an advantage of using function-call syntax as Howard suggests is that you can implement log levels and then not waste time at runtime if this message is below the current level.

Comment: @M.M Log levels? And I can't think what the destructor would do. It would be great to have both solutions if you're up for it.

Comment: "log levels" means you can assign different priority to log messages, and then at runtime (e.g. in response to a config file) decide what to show or not show. For example you might log information that would be useful for debugging, but you normally don't want to log that unless someone is having an issue and decides to turn it on.

Comment: @M.M Ah. Whereas using #ifdef would of course be compile-time only. Makes sense. Although, streams do accept arguments like e.g. `std::fixed` via the `<<` operator?

Comment: Yes. BTW that's another reason to use a setup like I was suggesting; the way you have it now, flags will be 'sticky', e.g. your `fixed` will persist until it is unset, which can mess with other log messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a variadic template function (say `log_it`) that takes `AN_ENUM` plus a variable number of items to log, locks the `mutex` once, and then streams everything to `a_stringstream`.  For example:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class save_stream
{
    std::ostream&      os_;
    char               fill_;
    std::ios::fmtflags flags_;
    std::streamsize    precision_;

public:
    ~save_stream()
    {
        os_.fill(fill_);
        os_.flags(flags_);
        os_.precision(precision_);
    }

    save_stream(const save_stream&) = delete;
    save_stream& operator=(const save_stream&) = delete;

    explicit save_stream(std::ostream& os)
        : os_(os)
        , fill_(os.fill())
        , flags_(os.flags())
        , precision_(os.precision())
        {}
};

struct log
{
    std::mutex mut;
    std::stringstream a_stringstream;
};

std::vector<log> logs(10);

enum : std::size_t {AN_ENUM};

void
log_one(std::size_t)
{
}

template <class Arg0, class ...Args>
void
log_one(std::size_t log, Arg0 const& arg0, Args const& ...args)
{
    logs[log].a_stringstream << arg0;
    log_one(log, args...);
}

template <class ...Args>
void
log_it(std::size_t log, Args const& ...args)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(logs[log].mut);
    save_stream s{logs[log].a_stringstream};
    logs[log].a_stringstream << "log " << log << " says : ";
    log_one(log, args...);
    logs[log].a_stringstream << '\n';
}
```

This isn't a huge amount of code.  `log_it` takes an integral constant, uses that to index into `logs` to lock the mutex, spits out the prefix string, and then calls `log_one` with the constant log index and the variable number of arguments to log out.

`log_one` then simply logs the first argument, and then recursively calls `log_one` on the rest of the pack.

It can be used like this:

```
log_it(AN_ENUM, std::fixed, std::setprecision(3), "i = ", 4.5);
log_it(AN_ENUM,                                   "j = ", 4.5);
```

which results in `logs[0].a_stringstream` holding:

```
log 0 says : i = 4.500
log 0 says : j = 4.5
```

I'm sure the syntax can be finessed to something even prettier, but this gets the basic idea across:  Pass a variable number of args, lock at the top of the call stack, and then process each arg one by one.

"Log levels" could be just another argument to `log_it`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason why this template overload<< member won't work:

```
template<typename param>
auto operator<<(param &&Param)
{
    boost::lock_guard <boost::mutex> lock(mut);

    a_stringstream << std::forward<param>(Param);

    return *this;
}
```

I have no idea what you read that might suggest that this kind of an approach won't work, but whatever you read, it's wrong. My example might need a few tweaks, here and there, depending on your actual class, but theoretically it should be eminently doable.

Comment: This will release the lock between every output value, potentially allowing another thread to output something in between what should be contiguous output (e.g., between `a_double` and `a_string` in OP's example).

Comment: You can still do this, but you will have to do more work. Basically: have this template instantiate a shared_ptr containing the lock-guard, and a pointer to this. Have this template return the shared_ptr, and forward the initial operator<< parameter to it. Declare a second non-member operator<< template on the shared_ptr itself, that contains the payload in my example. End result: the lock is acquired once, and persist for the entire sequence of <<s. If you can't get non-member operator<< working on shared_ptr, wrap the shared_ptr in a class, and implement a 2nd operator<< on that.

Comment: ...continued. Much harder, and performance might suck, if your app logs heavily, but still doable. Have you considered not using an operator<<, but a variadic log() function, like: log("something", a_double,a_string)?

Comment: Its good to be reminded how complex C++ is and how much I still don't know. I looked at one example and for some reason assumed that argument had to have the same type as the return value for `operator<<`. The description of `std::forward` is confusing and I can't figure out why its necessary. And luckily, in my case, the only possible time for contention is periodic calls to swap the stringstream when writing to disk, so your basic version should work for me.